# Manually evaluating math formula from a string

Tags: actionscript-3, parsing, math

I know there are solutions to evaluate math formulas with AS3: Using MathParser, or port it to JavaScript and many others.

But what if I want to manually evaluate a math formula, without using any built libraries?
It should be able to solve this: `1+(2*5+(9-6)/(5-2))+(6/2)*5`

This is how I intend to go about it:

1. Seperate the string literal with left and right brackets.
2. Sort the result with its priority (by scanning the string from left to right, every
   time it sees a left bracket then priority increases. Every time it sees a right bracket
   then decreases).
3. Calculate the results from the one with the highest priority.

However, I have not been able to successfully implement it yet.

Comment: I know eval is evil, and all that, but would that be the solution?

Comment: Search term "expression parsing", starting links - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser,  http://www.smccd.net/accounts/hasson/C++2Notes/ArithmeticParsing.html

Comment: i'm sorry, but i don't understand the second link well.

Comment: eval() isn't available in AS3.

Comment: Natively - isn't available, but you can use 
third-party libs like http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/

Comment: @RomanTrofimov OP does say "But what if I want to manually evaluate a math formula, without using any built libraries?"

Comment: @Kev Yes, it was just a remark, I didn't pretend to an answer.

Comment: @RomanTrofimov - ja, didn't know if you were preparing an answer based on an ext lib, thought I'd just save you the time :)

Answer (score 0):

Transform your expression into [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) using the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) and evaluate it. There's a good example in the second article.

Comment: cool, this is quite tricky. would you mind if i ask for further help if i have any problem understanding this?

Comment: It's all there. Follow the example.